# Website Defaced - Fix Redirect

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, deface

my website has been defaced. I went into the website files and found the php file they injected and deleted it, but all the webpages still attempt to redirect to it. The .htaccess file was modified as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/deface.php
RewriteRule ^ /deface.php [R=301]
```

Even when removing this file, all the webpages still attempt to redirect go the php file listed here. Any tips to solving this problem?

Comment: The server's been compromised. You can't trust it. Take it off line and put a new one in its place from a known good backup (with all the latest security updates applied).

Comment: To clarify... You don't have a local copy of the code you can restore?

Comment: Clear your browser's cache